# Trouble with a Unity 3D movement script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, computer-science

[image of the scene.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26fvo.png) I was using a tutorial online, then ran into issues when the code didn't work properly.

My main issue is with the isGrounded variable. When used, it doesnt allow my sprite to jump, when its job is to prevent doube-jumps by only allowing you to jump when touching the ground, everything is linked up to the in-engine components, and i think the main issue is with the line:

`isGrounded=Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);`

the rest of the code is below. thanks for reading.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 10f;
    Vector3 velocity;
    public float gravity = -20f;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;
    public float speedManager = 1.5f;
    bool isGrounded;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if( isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -10f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");



        Vector3 move = transform.right * (x / speedManager) + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

   


        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -10f * gravity);
        }

            controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `public LayerMask groundMask;` is set in the component and your ground GameObject's layer is the same as `groundMask`.

Edit:

You can add this piece of code to your class to check if the ground check is performed in the correct position:

```
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance);
    }
```

Comment: they both are, i just checked and they are both used where they should be in the engine and the code

Comment: I've updated my answer with a suggestion on how you can make sure if the position you are checking is the position you want to check

Comment: ive implemented this, and the result allows me to jump when im on the border between 2 steps only, and it lets me double jump when i reach a certain altitude.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what the scene looks like in the example you've described above?

Comment: ive uploaded an image of the scene at the top of the problem description

Comment: i have now fixed the script. the code is now in the question, thanks for your help!